# Is the limit of a function that oscillates just one time defined or undefined?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

If the limit of a function oscillates for just one value of $x$ and after that it still goes for example to $0$ (lets say is constantly descending), for all the others values of $x$ without any other oscillation, is this enough to say that the limit of the function is undefined or is it still defined?

An example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc3Kl.png)

Comment: Limit of what?  Limit as $x\to\infty$ for a specific individual function?  All that matters is tail behavior.  Any temporary behavior that occurs within a finite distance to the origin is completely irrelevant.  Compare your question to asking if the sequence $1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\dots$ where every entry in the sequence after this point is $1$ converges or not.  Of course it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is still defined.

For example, let's say that $x\rightarrow0$ in the following function.

$$ f(x)=x\sin\frac{1}{x}$$

This function oscillates infinitely many times near zero, yet $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} f(x)=0$.